# Flipswitch for guizmodns

Tags: cydia, tweak

I was wondering if someone can provide me the code to make a flipswitch for guizmodns.

I can put it all together and compile it but I dont know enough to make the switch part.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Flipswitch tutorial from the iPhone Dev Wiki:
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Flipswitch

The switches written by Ryan Petrich and a3tweaks are also a good place to help you out:
https://github.com/a3tweaks/Flipswitch/tree/master/Switches